# Python object creation failed

Tags: python, class, object

I am newbie in python so it may sound a stupid question.
Scenario:
I have a cluster class, while creating its instance i am supplying it with two default value which are nothing but coordinates for the centroid which will be of ty

```
from checkbox.lib.text import split
class point:
   x=0
   y=0
   def toString(self):
      return (self.x+ ':'+self.y)
   def __init__(self,a,b):
      self.x=a
      self.y=b

class cluster:

    points=[]
    centroid= point
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        centroid= point(a,b)
def kMeans(lis,k):
    length=len(lis)
    clusters=[]
    for i in range(k):
        clusters.append(cluster(2*i,2*i))
        print clusters[i].centroid.toString()
    for pt in lis:
        min=10
        centroidNum=0
        for i in range(k):
            dist=(abs(int(pt.x)- int(clusters[i].centroid.x))) +abs((int(pt.y) -    int(clusters[i].centroid.y)))
            if dist<min:
               min=dist
               centroidNum=i
        clusters[centroidNum].points.append(pt)
    for cl in clusters:
        print "Clusters"
        for pt in cl.points:
            print pt.toString()
def readValues():
    try:
        fileHandler = open('/home/sean/input/k_means.txt', 'r')

        for line in fileHandler:
            tokens=split(line,",")
            if len(tokens) == 2:
                tempObj=point(tokens[0].strip(),tokens[1].strip())
                list.append(tempObj)
    except IOError:
           print "File doesn't exist"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list=[]    
    readValues();
    kMeans(list,3)
```

I am tring to assign value to centroid thus passing in constructor. But i am getting below error:

`unbound method toString() must be called with point instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

I want the centroid to be a point so that i can access in rest of the program. 
Please help me how to assign value to centroid

input file has points in form 
1,2
3,5
4,3

Comment: fix the indentation of your code please

Comment: what should this toString() method do? Python is not Java and there is clearly the __str__() method for returning a stringish representation of the object.

Comment: In addition: your code does not demonstrate the described error...you are omitting code.

Comment: What should " centroid= point" do?

Comment: basically toString method will return the points in , separated format. like 2,10 which then be written to the output file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving us the full code for your problem.

Couple of general Python syntax issues first:

- Class names should be CamelCase (`class Point` and `class Cluster`)
- Function names should be lower case (`to_string(self):` )
- You've also got some random semicolons around there from Java(script) syntax I'm guessing.

It looks like the line

```
centroid = Point
```

is creating an unbound instance of `Point` (should be `centroid = Point()` but you'd also need to pass 2 arguments as `a` and `b`).

Try removing this line so the `Point()` instance is created in the `__init__` function of `Cluster`.

#### Edit 1:

Here's your problem;

In your `__init__` of `Cluster` you are setting a variable `centroid` but not applying it to the instance (`self`). As a result, it is trying to use `centroid = Point` you are setting within the instance, which is unbound.

Try this setup:

```
class cluster:

    points=[]
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.centroid = point(a,b)
```

I've got rid of the unnecessary (and wrong) initialisation of `centroid= point` and am now setting `centroid` as an attribute to the class in the `__init__` method.

Comment: hey Ewan i have updated the full code. I need centroid in cluster class so how should i assign values to it

Comment: @sean - try my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> unbound method toString() must be called with point instance as first
>   argument

usually occurs when you call an instance method of class on the class directly and instead of an instance of the object.

Example:

```
class foo(object):

    def bar(self):
        print 'bar'

print foo.bar()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "out", line 6, in <module>
    print foo.bar()
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

So you have to call

```
foo().bar()
```